# Android Webview onBackPressed Handle History

Tags: android, webview

My app is using WebView to navigate between web pages. It contains a registration form page, a success message page and a login form page. The app is continuing to the login page when the registration process is done, after the user presses the login button on the success message page, shown in the flow chart below.

[image]

When the user presses back when he/she is on the login form, I want to skip navigation back to the success message page, and go directly back to the registration page, effectively reversing the flow chart and removing the success message page from it, as shown in the modified flow chart below.

[image]

Below is what I have written so far, but the code is not working correctly, as it still navigates to the success message page when the user backpresses from the login page.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
  HTML5WebView mWebView;


 public void onBackPressed() {


    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.hideCustomView();

       if(mWebView.getUrl().equals("Success message URL")){

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                   .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                   .setTitle("Test App")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_EX);
                           android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                           mWebView.clearCache(true);
                           mWebView.clearHistory();
                           finish();
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
           AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
           alert.show();
       }
    }


    else
    {
        mWebView.hideCustomView();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
              .setTitle("Test App")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_EX);
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        // This above line close correctly
                        mWebView.clearCache(true);
                        mWebView.clearHistory();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you comparing like `if(mWebView.getUrl().equals("Success message URL"))` or have you replaced the String `"Success message URL"` with **actual url** in code?

Comment: im comparing that url..i can put it if you want

Comment: No. just wanted to confirm that you are comparing correctly. Did you debug and see if it goes in if?

Comment: yes..but that if statement is not executing..i have put sysout.and there is no out put on logcat..but page is navigating to the Sccess page when i back pressed..

Comment: Sysout (mWebView.getUrl()) before that if condition, and see if its correct url?

Comment: There is only one sysout on the logcat even i press 3 times back button.That IF is not executing ,but page is navigating? i dont know why

Comment: Have you added `mWebView.goBack();` in your code while setting up webview? If no, add.